# Logcat in Android Studio is not writing the tags that I told it

Tags: android-studio, logcat

I use, for example, Log.e("Throw Err: ", t.getMessage()); but on the logcat the tag is System.out instead of "Throw Err: ".

I was expecting that the column of the tag, printed on the Android Studio console, was "Throw Err: ". But instead I got a "System.out"